# About std::unique_prt() and decltype()

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

What does`std::unique_ptr<std::FILE, decltype(&close_file)> fp(std::fopen("demo.txt", "r"), &close_file);` mean ?

I konw `std::uqiue_ptr` is an unique pointer.  But i could not understand the entire expression.

Could anybody do me a favor?

```
  void close_file(std::FILE* fp) { std::fclose(fp); }

  std::cout << "Custom deleter demo\n";
  std::ofstream("demo.txt") << 'x'; // prepare the file to read
  {
      std::unique_ptr<std::FILE, decltype(&close_file)> fp(std::fopen("demo.txt", "r"),
                                                           &close_file);
      std::cout<<typeid((&close_file)).name()<<std::endl;
      if(fp) // fopen could have failed; in which case fp holds a null pointer
        std::cout << (char)std::fgetc(fp.get()) << '\n';
  }
```

Comment: What part are you specifically uncertain about? `decltype`, `&close_file`, or the template arguments of `std::unique_ptr`? Did your book or other study material have anything about this?

Comment: Given `void foo(int x) { };`, then `decltype(&foo)` is the type of `&foo`.

Comment: @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica Thank you for your attention.I know "std::unique_ptr".There is no doubt that `close_file` is the type of `void(*)(std::FILE*)`.So,what's the meaning of `&close_file` and `decltype(&close_file)`.As i am not a native speaker,  i could not get the idea though I have  saw some metria on the cpprefrence.I try hard to understand it,  but failed.

Comment: @Eljay I think `decltype(&foo)` should be `void(*)(std::FILE*)`, but i find it is PFvP8_IO_FILEE through std::cout<<typeid(decltype(&close_file)).name()<<std::endl. I could not get the idea.You could check it on godbolt.org/z/r3BjQV

Comment: `echo 'PFvP8_IO_FILEE' | c++filt` says `void (*)(_IO_FILE*)`

Comment: The string returned by `typeid(decltype(&close_file)).name()` is implementation defined.  It could be C++ text, it could be legible, it could be mangled, it could be a number, it could be a UUID.  It just has to be unique, and otherwise it is entirely up to the implementation.

Comment: @Eljay It's so kind of you.Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `void close_file(std::FILE* fp) { std::fclose(fp); }`

`decltype(&close_file)` is `void(*)(stdFILE*)` (function pointer).

You can provide custom deleter to `std::unique` and it is what is done here:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::FILE, decltype(&close_file)> fp(std::fopen("demo.txt", "r"),
                                                     &close_file);
```

I think it is nicer to have better deleter though:

```
struct file_closer
{
    void operator()(std::FILE* fp) const { std::fclose(fp); }
};
```

or even

```
template <auto* func>
using Functor = std::integral_constant<decltype(func), func>;

using file_closer = Functor<&std::fclose>;
```

used as

`std::unique_ptr<std::FILE, file_closer> fp(std::fopen("demo.txt", "r"));`

Comment: A lambda would also look nice here (at least a C++20 default-constructible one).

Comment: @ HolyBlackCat Lambda is supported since C++11.Why C++20 at least?

Comment: @sunshilong369: I think HolyBlackCat talked about template parameter: `std::unique_ptr<std::FILE, decltype([](std::FILE* file) { std::fclose(file); })>`. or `Functor<[](std::FILE* file) { std::fclose(file); }>`. (BTW, seems not nicer)

Comment: @jarod42 Glad to see you again.My heart is full of thanks to you.I understand `decltype(close_file)` is the type of `void(*)(stdFILE*)` (function pointer) .But i could not comprehend the meaning of aquiring the address of a function pointer(`&close_file`).And why `decltype(&close_file)` is the type of `void(*)(stdFILE*)` (function pointer)  too?

Comment: @sunshilong369: "Issue" is that function can decay to function pointer, so in most contexts `close_file` == `&close_file`. But `decltype(close_file)` is `void(stdFILE*)` whereas `decltype(&close_file)` is `void(*)(stdFILE*)`.

Comment: and you can provide custom deleter type to unique_ptr, you can also provide instance. With custom type as function pointer, youo have to provide which function pointer to use (if not provided, it would be `nullptr` which cannot be invoked).

Comment: @jarod42  Thank you for your clarification. Why "decltype(close_file) is void(stdFILE*) whereas decltype(&close_file) is void(*)(stdFILE*)."? Could you give some hint to dig deep?I wanna to make it clear.

Comment: `close_file` **is** a function. `&close_file` is a function pointer. `close_file` decays to function pointer in some contexts.

Comment: @sunshilong369 • It is obvious that you are finding this very confusing.  The reason is because it is very confusing.  Some things are just hard.  Keep in mind this quote, "When I am struggling with something, I sometimes think ‘Damn, this is hard for me. I wonder if I am stupid,’ and then I remember that I have a degree in astrophysics from Cal Tech; I must not be stupid." ~ Rock

Comment: @sunshilong369 & Jarod In C++20 lambdas with no captures are default-constructible, so you don't have to pass them to the constructor of `unique_ptr` (which was annoying). I wouldn't write a lambda directly in a template parameter though, I agree that it doesn't look good.

Comment: @Eljay Thank you for your encouragement.I would do my best.

Comment: @Jarod42 Sorry to trouble you again.I find that `std::unique_ptr` has several constructor overloads, one of which is `template<class T, class Deleter =std::default_delete<T> > class unique_ptr;`.  As you say:"you can provide custom deleter type to unique_ptr, you can also provide instance. With custom type as function pointer, you have to provide which function pointer to use." What confuse is that i could see any relation between `class Deleter =std::default_delete<T> ` and `function pointer`(why not just provide function, not the function pointer).Thank you.

Comment: @sunshilong369: `std::default_delete<T>` is not a function, but a functor, a class with `operator()` which acts as a function. Function pointer is just a type, you really need the value to call it.

Comment: @Jarod42  Thank you for your promote reply.I would read the related documentations to understand it.Thank you.